# How do i trigger input file manually?

Tags: javascript, jquery, file, input

```
<input type="text" />
<input type="file" />

$('input[type=text]').click(function() {
    $('input[type=file]').trigger('click');
});
```

I can get browse option (open dialog box) when I click the test box. But I cannot get browse option when I trigger text box's click using jquery trigger method.

```
$('input[type=file]').trigger('click');
```

How do i solve this?

Comment: It works for me http://jsfiddle.net/jUsB4/

Comment: Working for me!! http://jsfiddle.net/FrFD3/

Comment: Looks like @user2039104 JS code is writen before html (DOM not ready yet)

Answer (score 2):

What helped for me is to set the event-listener inside:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type=text]').click(function() {
        $('input[type=file]').trigger('click');
    });
}};
```

That used to do the trick for me. You might try it as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your code inside DOM ready handler `$(function() {...});` to make sure your DOM elements are loaded properly before executing your jQuery code.

```
$(function(
    $('input[type=text]').click(function() {
        $('input[type=file]').trigger('click');
    });
)};
```

Comment: Or just put your JS at the end of the page

Answer (score 0):

My belief is your selector `$('input[type=text]')` is not selecting , give it some id and use it like

```
$("#text").click(function(){
     $("#file").trigger("click");
});
```